# CURL и GREP для парсинга HTML

Tags: регулярные-выражения, curl, grep

Нужно вытащить таблицу, и значение из столбца определенного через ответ CURL

Пробовал так

```
curl -X POST $site -d $params -s | grep -Pio "<table\b[^>]*>((.|\n)*?)<\/table>"
```

Остановился на вытаскивании таблицы)
Почему-то не может прожевать REGEXP, видимо из-за переносов строк. Хотя регулярка вроде как рабочая, видимо дело в конфигурировании самого grep

Comment: Ваша регулярка не совсем рабочая, так как `((.|\n)*?)` — ужасно медленный шаблон, приводящий к зависанию программы. Вам нужен `grep -Pioz "(?s)<table\b[^>]*>\s*\K.*?(?=</table>|$)"`

Comment: Да оптимизация особая мне ни к чему. И консолька не зависает вроде а просто не віводит результатов. К слову та что вы привели, не совсем работает ```grep: unescaped ^ or $ not supported with -Pz```

Comment: Да, наверное, из-за двойных кавычек. Если использовать одинарные должно работать (сам шаблон верный, только я не тестировал). HTML вообще-то с регулярками не дружит. Если `$` ему не нравится, так пользуйте `\z` / `\Z`.

Comment: попробуйте beautiful soup